# Convert list of type Integer to map in java8?

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, type-conversion

I can construct a `Map<Integer, Integer>` from a `List` through a `for` statement like so

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 53, 66, 55, 99, 6989, 99, 33);

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer integer : integers) {
    map.put(integer, integer);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

But when I try to use streams

```
map = integers.stream().distinct().map(p -> p).collect(Collectors.toMap(integers::get, integers::get));
```

the code throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 53
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at com.me.lamda.LamdaOps.main(LamdaOps.java:30)
```

Why?

Comment: What do you think `Collectors.toMap(integers::get, integers::get)` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: ** :: I thought method reference would do that as it will get every element of list right,Coreect me if my assumption is wrong**

Comment: try this Map<Integer,Integer> map = integers.stream().distinct().map(p -> p).collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, Integer::intValue));

Comment: Use map = integers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, Integer::intValue)); because toMap expects arguments as ClassName::methodNameToBeCalledToGetTheDesiredValue

Comment: For that matter, what do you think `.map(p -> p)` does?

Comment: @shmosel  In this case nothing like any transfermation activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer::intValue` instead of `integers::get` because it expects the parameters to be like `ClassName::methodNameToBeCalledToGetTheDesiredValue`

Also, map(p->p) is redundant here as you are not mapping the value into something else.

Try this

```
    List<Integer> integers= Arrays.asList(1,2,53,66,55,99,6989,99,33);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = integers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, Integer::intValue));
    System.out.println(map);
```

Output : {33=33, 1=1, 66=66, 2=2, 99=99, 53=53, 55=55, 6989=6989}

Comment: Why? What does this do? What was wrong with their solution?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis ** Where can we use method reference ? Could you please help me on this? **

Comment: If grouping on Identity as Key and keeping values unique - [    Map<Integer,Integer> intMap2 =
         intList.stream().distinct().
         collect(Collectors.toMap((v)->{
          return intList.indexOf(v);
         }, Integer::intValue));